# Exportar a Excel en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quisiera saber como exportar de Asp.net un DataGrid a Excel (si saben de alguna otra forma favor de explicarla), me sale un error, esta comentado en la linea donde aparece:

```
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel ";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);;// <-- Aqui me sale el error:RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

    }
      public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Comment: El "Response.End()", lo puedes controlar con un catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
             
            }

Answer (score 0):

Este es un código para exportar un gridview muy similar que me funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Así se implementa**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código C#**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 protected void ExportToExcel()
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                GridView1.AllowPaging = true;

                GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el control GridView no tiene controles AJAX como padre esto debería funcionar:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ArchivoExportado.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#F0F0F0");

foreach (TableCell tableCell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    tableCell.Style["background-color"] = "#ffffff";
}

foreach (GridViewRow gridviewrow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    gridviewrow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    foreach (TableCell gridviewrowtablecell in gridviewrow.Cells)
    {
        gridviewrowtablecell.Style["background-color"] = "#ffffff";
    }
}

GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Si la grilla está dentro de controles AJAX:

- Colocar el botón o enlace que realiza la exportación fuera del control **UpdatePanel**.
- Agrega al **UpdatePanel** el trigger **PostBackTrigger** que apunte al botón que realiza la exportación.
- Se debe llamar al método **ScriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl()** pasando como parámetro el botón de exportación.
- De última, puedes hacer otra página **.aspx** que realice la exportación sin utilizar **UpdatePanel**.

Espero resulte útil.